# Array->Scalar Functions in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm using this:

```
=googlefinance("ukx","close","01/01/2012")
```

But it's frustratingly returning a 2x2 array with the value I need at location 2,2. I'm trying to just get that value returned (a scalar), but I can't figure out what function I need to grab that. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INDEX` function (see [reference](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs)) seems to do the trick:

```
=INDEX(googlefinance("ukx","close", "01/01/2012"); 2; 2)
```

returns 5696.7 (see [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmR0r1Y14zgydG03QS1Dd0dLRDA3SWgtLXp6TzV3d3c#gid=0)).

Comment: This works, but it doesn't work for the case mentioned, which brings in historical data, and returns it as a 2x2 array. I should have mentioned that A3 is a date.